# Doctrine2 Join on One to Zero or One

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Apparently Doctrine2 may not support One to Zero or One relationships very well, as discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/doctrine-user/-nR4C2Nn-Mk). However, the database structure shows up correctly for me when I try to do it, I'm just having issues trying to do an 'optional' join on that table.

Here are my entities:

```
<?
// User.php
class User {
    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Location")
     *  @JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     **/
    private $location;

    // Getters and setters...
}

// Location.php
class Location {
    // ...
}
```

Basically, this is copied from the [Doctrine2 docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-unidirectional) example for a One-To-One Association, plus a nullable attribute on the owning side's `@JoinColumn`.

My issues arise when I try to query the User table and include a Location if it exists.  Here is my attempt at making that happen:

```
$user = $this->entityManager->createQuery('SELECT u, l FROM e:User u JOIN u.location l WHERE u.email = ?1')
            ->setParameter(1, $email)
            ->getResult();
```

Scenario #1: email exists and location exists for that user

Result #1: User object with the location property hydrated

Scenario #2: email exists and location does not exist for that user

Result #2: Empty array

I'd like for scenario #2 to return a User object with the location property null, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is embarrassing, I obviously don't have my proper SQL thinking cap on (since it's DQL and all).  I needed to use a **LEFT JOIN**, not just a **JOIN**. This is the part where I slap myself in the face.

I just changed my query to this:

```
$user = $this->entityManager->createQuery('SELECT u, l FROM e:User u LEFT JOIN u.location l WHERE u.email = ?1')
            ->setParameter(1, $email)
            ->getResult();
```